# Dynamically added checkboxes in JQuery Mobile App not shown correctly in Android Browser

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, android-browser

I created a quizpage in a Jquery Mobile App with a set of dynamically added checkboxes. When opening the page with Chrome or Firefox the page looks good. But not in the Android default browser on my Tablet or Phone. I want to create a native package with Phonegap later. The look will be the same as in default browser.

I'm using Jquery 2.1.3 and JQuery Mobile 1.4.5

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="quiz">
<div id="quizHeader" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a" data-id="exp-header">
    <h1 id="quizHeadline"></h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" id="quizContent"></div>
<div id="quizFooter" data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-id="exp-footer">
```

Javascript:

```
    $("#quizContent").append('<fieldset id="quizCheckboxGroup" data-role="controlgroup"></fieldset>');

answersArr = [{id:1, answer:"Apfel"},{id:2, answer:"Banane"},{id:3, answer:"Orange"}];

for(var i=0; i<answersArr.length; i++){
    var a = answersArr[i];
    $("#quizCheckboxGroup").append('<input type="checkbox" name="quizCheckbox-'+a.id+'" id="quizCheckbox-'+a.id+'" value="'+a.id+'"><label for="quizCheckbox-'+a.id+'">'+a.answer+'</label>');
}

$("#quizContent").append('<a href="#" data-role="button" data-questiontype="mc" id="quizCheckButton">Antwort pr&uuml;fen</a>').enhanceWithin();
```

Screenshots:

[Checkboxes in Standard Android Browser](http://pl.vc/1xoni)

[Checkboxes in Chrome Browser](http://pl.vc/1mox2)

JS Fiddle:
jsfiddle.net/f5xkcc08/

Comment: Try running the script in the pagecreate event, and also, create all the DOM items as one string and append the whole thing once at the end. You updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/f5xkcc08/1/ .  See if that makes any difference

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried this, but unfortunately it has no effect. Also the page should load new data on each call, so pagecreate event is not suitable for my intention.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that the problem is somewhere in my data. I get the answers as result from a DB query and push them in the "answersArr" Array. Alternatively I created a second Array "answersArray" with hardcoded answers.

When I use "answersArr" in second for loop for creating the checkboxes, I get the problem mentioned above. When I use "answersArray" (the hardcoded one) all checkboxes look fine.

But I can't find a difference?! The console output of both arrays look good.

```
getQuestionsAnswers(question.id, function(answers){
    answersArr = new Array();
    for(var a=0; a<answers.length; a++){
        answersArr[a] = {
            id: answers.item(a).id,
            answer: answers.item(a).answer
        }
    }
    answersArray = new Array();
    answersArray[0] = {id:1, answer:"Cherry"}
    answersArray[1] = {id:2, answer:"Peanuts"}
    answersArray[2] = {id:3, answer:"Strawberry"}

    var html = '';
    html += '<fieldset id="quizCheckboxGroup" data-role="controlgroup">';

    for(var i=0; i<answersArr.length; i++){
        var a = answersArr[i];
        html += '<input type="checkbox" name="quizCheckbox-'+a.id+'" id="quizCheckbox-'+a.id+'" value="'+a.id+'" questionId="'+question.id+'"><label for="quizCheckbox-'+a.id+'">'+a.answer+'</label>';
    }
   html += '</fieldset>';
   html += '<a href="#" data-role="button" data-questiontype="mc" id="quizCheckButton">Antwort pr&uuml;fen</a>';
   $("#quizContent").append(html).enhanceWithin();
});
```